# In jmeter How to configure test plan with different duration and threads rampup

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, duration, group

In my JMeter test plan, I aim to execute three user groups over an 11-hour(39600 seconds )duration. For the first user group, I intend to add a new thread every 60 seconds.
For the second group, the plan is to add 1 thread every 2 seconds.
And third group 2 threads every 1 second

How can I configure the Thread Groups to achieve this specific thread addition pattern over the defined test duration?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.

With "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you need to set or let us know the total number of users in order to be able to calculate ramp-up period.

For example if you have 60 users:

- new thread every 60 seconds - ramp-up period would be 3600
- 1 thread every 2 seconds - ramp-up period would be 120
- 2 threads every 1 seconds - ramp-up period would be 30

If you change the number of users - amend the ramp-up period proportionally/accordingly.

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)

You might also find **[Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups)** JMeter Plugins Bundle useful, they provides visual way of controlling ramp-up, ramp-down, time to hold the load, spikes, etc. It might be easier for your to use.

Comment: For group 1 - 60 users.   For group 2 200 and group 3 200 users will be hitting application continued for 11 hours